# How to know which function overloading gcc selects

Tags: c++, gcc, overloading

This is my context:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace na {
    enum XXX { X1, X2 };

    std::string to_string(XXX x) {
        static const std::map<XXX, std::string> MAP { {X1, "X1"}, {X2, "X2"} };

        return MAP.at(x);
    }
}

namespace nb {
    enum YYY { Y1 = 1001, Y2 = 1002 };
}

typedef char priority;

std::string to_string(priority p) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << p;
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    na::XXX x = na::X1;

    std::cout << "x: " << to_string(x) << "\n";

    nb::YYY y = nb::Y2;

    std::cout << "y: " << to_string(y) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The call to `to_string(y)` is a "mistake" because no function `to_string` exists for the type `nb::YYY`. But in fact this works !

I compile this with :

```
g++ -o main.o -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
g++ -o function_overloading main.o
```

And this compiles with no error, no warning. In that simple case I know that when GCC does the name lookup for `to_string(y)` it finds `to_string(priority)` but in a big project, it is not simple to find which function GCC has chosen.

So, is there a way to determine which function GCC chose, "a posteriori", by examining the .o, or by passing an option to GCC ?

I use GCC 4.7.2 on linux.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger? Some IDEs can also manage to locate the actually used overload and provide that info for code navigation.

Comment: you can avoid this by making `priority` a non-integral type, like an `enum` eg.

Comment: `std::string na::to_string(XXX x)` is not known in the scope of main, so this would be obvious.

Comment: @scones - that works fine due to [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Learned something new today, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might objdump with source information. Lets try your example (I will use gcc 4.9.2 for clarity:

```
g++ -c -O0 -gdwarf-2 gccover.cpp -std=c++11
objdump -Sdr gccover.o >& gccover.dis
```

You will see:

```
<_ZN2na9to_stringENS_3XXXE>:
std::string to_string(XXX x)
```

and

```
<_Z9to_stringc>:
std::string to_string(priority p)
```

Now just go to point of call and look what is actually called.

```
      std::cout << "y: " << to_string(y) << "\n";
 296: 8b 45 e8              mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
 299: 0f be d0              movsbl %al,%edx
 29c: 48 8d 45 e0           lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 2a0: 89 d6                 mov    %edx,%esi
 2a2: 48 89 c7              mov    %rax,%rdi
 2a5: e8 00 00 00 00        callq  2aa <main+0x76>
      2a6: R_X86_64_PC32  _Z9to_stringc-0x4
```

I think, everything is clear.

Comment: Indeed, this is clear ! I added -C to objdump to demangle. Thanks !